# Variable not defined (TypeError: Cannot read property 'todos' of null) ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is all my code below .
When I run it I receive this error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'todos' of null )todos not found at this line `var todos=this.state.todos;`

> My App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
    getInitialState (){
        return{
            todos:['washup',"hi","hello","up"]
        }
    }

render() {
      var todos=this.state.todos;
```

> Added Code here

```
 todos=todos.map(function(item,index){
              return(
                <li>item</li>
              );
              }

      );
```

> Till here

```
    return (
      <div id="App">
            <ul>{todos}</ul>
          )
   } )

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

> This is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from `'./registerServiceWorker';`

ReactDOM.render(<div>
                     <App>Here is my Buttonas</App>
                </div>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**EDIT**
New Error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

At this line  todos=todos.map(function(item,index){

What is the error now?

Comment: You should check your code. You have mistakes in your render method.

Comment: I am a newbie tell me what code you want, I created this app using npm create-app method

Comment: You have 3 additional brackets after the <ul> element and before the ending </div> tag in your render() method in App.js. This will cause error.

Comment: I deleted some code to make it easy for u ppl to understand ,no they are not useless ,just my mistake in failing to remove them before posting here

Comment: You should **not use `getInitialState`**. It is wrong. You still do not correctly initialize your state. That's why `todos` is still `undefined` and `undefined` does obviously not have a `map()` method. See my answer on how to correctly initialize component state.

Answer (score 4):

`getInitialState()` is only used with `createReactClass()`. When using ES6 classes you just set state as a property:

See [Setting the Initial State](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state) in the react docs:

> In ES6 classes, you can define the initial state by assigning
>   `this.state` in the `constructor`:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todos: ['washup',"hi","hello","up"],
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

or just

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        todos: ['washup',"hi","hello","up"],
    }

    // ...
}
```

> With `createReactClass()`, you have to provide a separate
>   `getInitialState` method that returns the initial state:

```
var App = createReactClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            todos: ['washup',"hi","hello","up"],
        };
    },

    // ...
});
```

Comment: @shutup1 Please do not ask new questions inside your question. Create a new question instead.

Comment: @shutup1 But to answer it. Did you change the initialization of your component state to be conform with es6 classes? Because it is still `undefined`. That's why you get this error. **Do not use `getInitialState`**. It is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing the state older way in a newer version of reactjs. I already appreciate the answer of trixn. But here's also a solution without removing your current code:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = getInitialState (){
        return{
            todos:['washup',"hi","hello","up"]
        }
    }
```

Notice that I have assigned state to the getInitialState and will work fine because this returns the object `{todos:['washup',"hi","hello","up"]}` which is similar to this:

```
state = {todos:['washup',"hi","hello","up"]}
```

---

Next, when your component is being rendered first time your todos might get undefined as you stated. To resolve this issue you may add a condition:

```
todos && todos.length && todos.map(...)
```

Now, the map function will only run if the todos is not undefined and it has length ie. it has at least one value.

Answer (score 1):

It caused because you didn't define todos in your state, to achieve the soloution, make a constructor in your class and set a todos variable in your state, you can set in empty or null in the constructor and fill it later, then you can use it in your render section, comment if you need further information and also read react life cycle in the official website

Answer (score 1):

With createClass you can use `getInitialState`:

```
const App = React.createClass({
      getInitialState() {
        return { /* initial state */ };
      },
    });
```

but with ES6 classes you do like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {todos:['washup',"hi","hello","up"]};
  }
}
```

EDITED: get items through map:

```
  class App extends Component {
    state={
      todos: ['washup', "hi", "hello", "up"]
    }

render() {
      var todos= this.state.todos.map((item)=>{
        return <li>{item}</li>
      })

    return (
      <div id="App">
            <ul>{todos}</ul>

           </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: see my EDITED answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You should define you todos in the state
App.Js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
       todos:['washup',"hi","hello","up"]
    }
  }

render() {


    return (
      <div id="App">
            <ul>{this.state.todos}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```